# ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1) error when running openldap in a docker container under ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, docker, openldap

My environment is like below:
Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS running as VM on VMware ESXi 6
Openldap running in a docker container

I get the following error when running any ldap command. for e.g.

```
username@hostname:~$ docker exec ls-ldap ldapsearch -x -d 1
ldap_create
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP localhost:389
ldap_new_socket: 4
ldap_prepare_socket: 4
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying ::1 389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 4 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect: 
connect errno: 111
ldap_close_socket: 4
ldap_new_socket: 4
ldap_prepare_socket: 4
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 127.0.0.1:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 4 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect: 
connect errno: 111
ldap_close_socket: 4
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Any help or thoughts would be very much appreciated. I have tried to edit ldap.conf file with TLS_REQCERT allow as well but no luck. Looking forward to answers. Thank you for having a look at this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since `errno 111` means 'Connection Refused', check your LDAP_URI or LDAP_HOST and your IP/PORT configurations.

It does not look like a TLS error, a certificate isn't relevant until you have a connection.